# How to automate parameters passed into pandas.read_sql?

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I am trying to create a methodology for passing parameters automatically through something like `locals()`, similarly to how f-strings work.

How it currently works

```py
import pandas as pd

def my_func(conn, string_id, date, integer_ids):
    sql = f"""    
    select * from TABLE a
    where STRING_ID = '{string_id}'
    and DATE = {date}
    and INTEGER_ID in ({','.join(map(str, integer_ids))})"""
    df = pd.read_sql(sql, conn)
    return df
```

However, this approach means I cannot copy-paste the SQL into SQL developer or similar, and run it from there. So I would like an approach that makes use of parameters instead.

There seems to be two problems with that

1. Parameters must be literals, so its not possible to pass along lists
2. I need to create a dictionary manually, and cannot simply pass something like `locals()`

How I would like it to work would be something like the example below (which obviously doesn't work)

```py
import pandas as pd

def my_func(conn, string_id, date, integer_ids):
    sql = """    
    select * from TABLE
    where STRING_ID = :string_id
    and DATE = :date
    and INTEGER_ID in :integer_ids"""
    df = pd.read_sql(sql, conn, params=locals())
    return df
```

---

**EDIT**: Thanks to perl, I now have a working solution to my problem

```py
def read_sql(sql, conn, params):
    # Finds all words following a ":" sign in the sql
    for p in re.findall(':(\w+)', sql):
        if isinstance(params.get(p), (tuple, list)):
            ext_params = {f'{p}_{i:03d}': p_i for i, p_i in enumerate(params.get(p))}
            sql = sql.replace(f':{p}', f"(:{', :'.join(ext_params)})")
            params.update(ext_params)

    sql_text = sqlalchemy.text(sql)
    return pd.read_sql(sql_text, conn, params=params)


def my_func(conn, string_id, date, integer_ids):
    sql = """    
    select * from TABLE
    where STRING_ID = :string_id
    and DATE = :date
    and INTEGER_ID in :integer_ids"""
    df = read_sql(sql, conn, locals())
    return df
```

---

**EDIT2**: For anyone finding this question, I have since then extended the solution a bit to cover issues where lists longer than 1000 elements are passed

```py
def generate_sql(sql: str, params: dict = None, param_key: str = ':') -> List[Tuple[sqlalchemy.text, dict]]:
    if params is None:
        params = dict()
    max_sql_params = 1000

    out = []
    # Finds all words following a ":" sign in the query
    for p in set(re.findall(f"{param_key}(\w+)", sql)):
        if isinstance(params.get(p), (tuple, list, np.ndarray)):
            # Recursively call function for variables with more than 1000 elements
            if len(params[p]) > max_sql_params:
                new_params = params.copy()  # NB: Shallow copy sufficient as param keys are tuples, lists or arrays
                new_params[p] = params[p][max_sql_params:]
                out.extend(generate_sql(sql=sql, params=new_params, param_key=param_key))
            extra_params = {f"{p}_{i:03d}": p_i for i, p_i in enumerate(params[p][:max_sql_params])}
            sql = sql.replace(f":{p}", f"(:{', :'.join(extra_params)})")
            params.update(extra_params)

    sql_text = sqlalchemy.text(sql)
    out.append((sql_text, params))
    return out


def read_sql(sql: str, conn: sqlalchemy.engine, params: dict = None) -> pd.DataFrame:
    sql_tuples = generate_sql(sql=sql, params=params)
    df = pd.concat(pd.read_sql(sql=s, con=conn, params=p) for s, p in sql_tuples)

    return df
```

Comment: would return df, sql workl? at least you'd get the sql with the parameters into a string you can print() and cut/paste?

Comment: @JonathanLeon that would require i run the code to get a string that can be copy pasted, i need something that works without running the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use parametrized queries by wrapping the query in `sqlalchemy.text` and converting lists to tuples. For example:

```
def my_func(conn, min_number, letters):
    # convert lists to tuples
    letters = tuple(letters)
    
    # wrap sql in sqlalchemy.text
    sql = sqlalchemy.text("""    
        SELECT *
        FROM letters
        WHERE
            number >= :min_number AND
            letter in :letters""")
    
    # read and return the resulting dataframe
    df = pd.read_sql(sql, conn, params=locals())
    return df

my_func(conn, 10, ['a', 'b', 'c', 'x', 'y', 'z'])
```

Output:

```
  letter  number
0      x      23
1      y      24
2      z      25
```

---

For completeness of the example, the following was used as a test table:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'letter': list(string.ascii_lowercase),
    'number': range(len(string.ascii_lowercase))})
df.to_sql('letters', conn, index=False)
```

---

**Update:** Here's a possible workaround for Oracle to make it work with lists:

```
def get_query(sql, **kwargs):
    for k, v in kwargs.items():
        vs = "','".join(v)
        sql = sql.replace(f':{k}', f"('{vs}')")
    return sql

def my_func(conn, min_number, letters):
    sql_template = """    
        SELECT *
        FROM letters
        WHERE
            number >= :min_number AND
            letter in :letters
    """
    # pass list variables to `get_query` function as named parameters
    # to get parameters replaced with ('value1', 'value2', ..., 'valueN')
    sql = sqlalchemy.text(
        get_query(sql_template, letters=letters))
    
    df = pd.read_sql(sql, conn, params=locals())
    return df

my_func(conn, 10, ['a', 'b', 'c', 'x', 'y', 'z'])
```

---

**Update 2:** Here's the `get_query` function that works with both strings and numbers (enclosing in quotes strings, but not numbers):

```
def get_query(sql, **kwargs):
    # enclose in quotes strings, but not numbers
    def q(x):
        q = '' if isinstance(x, (int, float)) else "'"
        return f'{q}{x}{q}'
    
    # replace with values
    for k, v in kwargs.items():
        sql = sql.replace(f':{k}', f"({','.join([q(x) for x in v])})")

    return sql
```

For example:

```
sql = """    
SELECT *
FROM letters
WHERE
    number in :numbers AND
    letters in :letters
"""

get_query(sql,
          numbers=[1, 2, 3],
          letters=['A', 'B', 'C'])
```

Output:

```
SELECT *
FROM letters
WHERE
    number in (1,2,3) AND
    letters in ('A','B','C')
```

Comment: Your code works excellent for non-list variables. However if I supply a list (as a tuple), it produces the following error: `sqlalchemy.exc.NotSupportedError: (cx_Oracle.NotSupportedError) Variable_TypeByValue(): unhandled data type tuple`

Comment: @oskros Ah, so you're connecting to Oracle, right? I tested mine on Postgres

Comment: Yes, using oracle

Comment: Apparently it's not supported in Oracle driver the same way it is in Postgres (see [here](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html#binding-multiple-values-to-a-sql-where-in-clause)). The workaround that they recommend is generating the `sql` in code, which is of course what we're trying to avoid here...

Comment: I see, so perhaps there is no solution to my issue then. That is unfortunate.. If I don't get another solution I'll accept your answer - thanks

Comment: @oskros Maybe one option that's reasonably OK is to keep the SQL template, and use a helper function to replace `:param` with values where needed (so, I would only pass the list variables to `get_query`). I've posted an update with an example. Please see if this helps

Comment: And if the overall idea works for you, we can improve `get_query` to dynamically check for numeric types that don't need to be enclosed in quotes and generate the list of values accordingly

Comment: that looks nice, yeah a dynamic `get_query`  that replaces list variables automatically might do the trick

Comment: @oskros Cool, see update 2 for updated `get_query` function that can handle numeric types as well

Comment: just added a `if isinstance(v, (tuple, list)):` to your loop over params, then I can pass `locals()` instead of custom kwargs and it can work fully automatically with a SQL that can be run from SQL interpreter as well - so thanks a lot! -- I edited my question with the final solution

Comment: Great, and actually maybe then it's better to loop over all `:param` strings in the `sql` statement instead of looping over the `locals()` (because then we only search and replace what's needed), right? We can get all parameter names with `re.findall(':(\w+)', sql)`

Comment: And by the way, depending on where the data comes from, it could be a good idea to make sure we get no SQL injections there, if we no longer use the parametrized statements

Comment: That is actually a great idea, and instead of splicing the SQL with the values, we could instead change it to `(:param1, :param2, ...)` such that handling of string and dates are done automatically - edited my question with this approach

Comment: @oskros That's really cool! And it's all parametrized now, so it's automatically safe from SQL injections

Answer (score 1):

why not this :

```
import pandas as pd

def my_func(conn, string_id, date, integer_ids):
    sql = """    
    select * from RISK
    where STRING_ID = %s
    and DATE = %s
    and INTEGER_ID in %s"""
    df = pd.read_sql(sql, conn, (string_id, date,integer_ids))
    return df
```

Comment: because it cant be copy pasted into an SQL interpreter

Comment: @oskros i'm not following , copy pasting what?

Comment: copy pasting the SQL string directly from the `.py` file into an SQL interpreter - the `%s` will give a syntax error

Comment: I see , but what would you want that?

Comment: I want SQLs stored in separate `.sql` files, which are then executed either directly through an SQL interpreter by inputting parameter values, or loaded by python to run in a script - this is needed as some of my companys code runs with pl/sql and other stuff is coded in python

Comment: So you don’t want to load data in python at all if I understand correctly, you just want to prepare sql statements . Right?

Comment: No, I want the same SQLs to both be able to load data into python, and be copied into SQL interpreters to load data there as well